# Apache Zeppelin: configuration of python interpreter on Windows

Tags: python, apache-zeppelin

I'm having some troubles with running Zeppelin Python notebook on Windows. It looks like some output problem with several `SyntaxError: invalid syntax` errors. E.g. the code

```
%python
import numpy as np
print np.random.randn(10)
```

results in

```
                    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
[ 0.3144414   0.2340006   0.86525395 -0.24519029 -1.19862891 -0.88127259
 -1.64757093  1.39753151 -0.50873422 -1.39649112]
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    z._displayhook()
                    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
  File "<stdin>", line 1

    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
  File "<stdin>", line 1
```

Similarly when plotting with `matplotlib` the code is executed, but the actual figures are not shown (perhaps due to the output problems):

```
%python
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.plot([1, 2, 3])
```

gives an error:

```
                    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
[<matplotlib.lines.Line2D object at 0x0000000004D737B8>]
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    z._displayhook()
                    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
  File "<stdin>", line 1

    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
  File "<stdin>", line 1
ERROR
```

I'd appreciate any suggestions or help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an easy work around. In the Interpreters management section
under the python interpreter set the following ***zeppelin.python*** property value to ***python -i***

`zeppelin.python                         python -i`

(worked for me with v2.7.13)

Comment: Great! Thanks, @Ariel, it worked for me perfectly: Zeppelin 0.7.0 and Python 2.7.13 / Anaconda.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that Zeppelin doesn't currently support Windows's using python interpreter. You'll need to spin up a different envirornment using a VM.

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ZEPPELIN-1436